# on_delete='CASCADE' seems to have no effect

Tags: python, peewee

I have a many-to-many relationship between two models, `User` and `Role`, implemented via an intermediary table, `UserRoleThrough`, which has two `ForeignKeyField`s: one referencing `User`, and another referencing `Role`. As I understand from the docs, [ON DELETE](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) functionality is supported by initializing `ForeignKeyField` with an `on_delete` argument. Though it's not very clear what values `on_delete` can take, the [documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#ForeignKeyField) gives an example, e.g. `'CASCADE'`. This being said, `on_delete='CASCADE'` seems to have no effect, as attempting to delete a row from one of the parent tables throws an error.

```
peewee.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Inspecting the generated schema with a database browser reveals that the foreign keys were not declared with ON DELETE.

```
CREATE TABLE "userrolethrough" (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "user_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "role_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "user" ("id"),
     FOREIGN KEY ("role_id") REFERENCES "role" ("id")
)
```

So what I'm doing wrong here? How do I get `on_delete` to work? Here's a minimal reproducible example using Python 3.6 and Peewee 3.0.2.

```
import peewee

db_proxy = peewee.Proxy()

class BaseModel(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db_proxy

class User(BaseModel):
    name = peewee.CharField()

class Role(BaseModel):
    name = peewee.CharField()

class UserRoleThrough(BaseModel):
    user = peewee.ForeignKeyField(User, on_delete='CASCADE')
    role = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Role, on_delete='CASCADE')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = peewee.SqliteDatabase('test.db')
    db.pragma('foreign_keys', 1, permanent=True)
    db_proxy.initialize(db)

    tables = [
        User,
        Role,
        UserRoleThrough
    ]
    db.create_tables(tables)

    isaac = User.create(name='Isaac')
    admin = Role.create(name='Admin')
    UserRoleThrough.create(user=isaac, role=admin)
    User.delete().execute()
```

Comment: This was fixed in 3.0.6: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#306

Comment: @coleifer could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed in 3.0.6: github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#306